# Auth0 - how long does the user stay logged in?

Tags: single-page-application, auth0

With Auth0, Using the SPA example, After performing a login, I see that that the user stays logged in on the next session without having to re-enter it’s credentials.

Two questions:

1. On the client side, I see that a cookie is created that enables the user to stay logged in without having to open the login screen. It looks like the default expiration time is 22 hours. Is there any way to extend this time frame?
2. Even if the the cookie expires, I see that the login screen does not require the user to re-enter it’s credentials and sends the token automatically. How long is the device authenticated without having to re-enter the user credentials? And can this be modified?

Thanks!

```
let auth0 = null;
const isAuthenticated = await auth0.isAuthenticated();



if(!isAuthenticated)
{
    console.log('Not Authenticated, redirecting to login page');

    await auth0.loginWithRedirect({
    redirect_uri: window.location.href
    });
}
else
{
    console.log('Authenticated');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Auth0 community form (Silent authentication was needed):

https://community.auth0.com/t/how-long-does-the-user-stay-logged-in-and-it-can-be-extended/38871